# conditional sum on list with Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I am struggling to reduce a list via a conditional sum, in this case, I would like to add the similar elements of a list

`[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]` would become `[0, 3, 0, 1, 0]` or just `[3, 1]`

I have tried foldr and foldr but I am struggling with the list constructor functions, any thoughts on how to complete this?

Comment: Hint: take a look at `groupBy`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy

Comment: I would try explicit recursion here. Folds look harder to apply in this case.

Comment: Thanks Willem Van Onsem, all solved with groupBy, just getting into FP. 

sum <$> groupBy (==) [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]

Comment: `groupBy (==)` is `group`!

Answer (score 1):

It looks from the comments that you've already resolved the issue, but I'll formalize the answer.

In order to find the adjacent similar elements, we use [`group`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group), from `Data.List`.

```
group [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
> [[0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0], [1], [0]]
```

Then we can map over that output the `sum` function, which adds up all the items in a list.

```
fmap sum . group $ [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
> [0, 3, 0, 1, 0]
```

It looks like you also want to remove the zeros. This can be done with `filter`, like so:

```
filter (/= 0) . fmap sum . group $ [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
> [3, 1]
```